# How to set HTTP request MOVE using HttpURLConnection?

Tags: java, http, httpurlconnection

How to set HTTP request method MOVE using `HttpURLConnection` ?

Using `HttpURLConnection` or libraries that rely on that class, the code is throwing an exception `Caused by: java.net.ProtocolException: Invalid HTTP method: MOVE`.
So I guess the `MOVE` method is not supported by the Java platform.

Is there a patch or workaround for this issue / limitation? The workaround could be another java library for creating HTTP requests.

**EDIT:** Note that the `MOVE` verb is supported [WebDav HTTP extension](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebDAV). There is also [`PATCH` extension](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5789) that was later added to the protocol.

For reference here is SkyDrive API with the [move](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/live/hh826531.aspx#move) feature we are trying to implement.

Note that the [Ruby platform supports the `MOVE` method](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0/libdoc/net/http/rdoc/Net/HTTP/Move.html). *I wonder why java does not supports or even allow those extensions*.

Comment: There is no `HTTP` request `MOVE`, see the [http methods](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol#Request_methods)

Comment: You want to use GET or POST for your request.

Comment: Only GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, HEAD are supported (by both Java and HTTP). What does this MOVE protocol is supposed to do?

Comment: It's one of the methods in the WebDAV protocol.

Comment: I don't understand why this topic is closed. It is a legit question and based on Microsoft http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/live/hh243648.aspx#http_verbs the COPY and MOVE are standard HTTP verbs, but as far as I know, they are not in standarad HTTP verbs. Can someone tell me why this is so confusing ?

Comment: Agreed HTTP is supposed to be extensible. Quoting [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol) : > *There is no limit to the number of methods that can be defined* and *this allows for future methods to be specified* without breaking existing infrastructure. For example, WebDAV defined 7 new methods and RFC5789 specified the PATCH method.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a bug in HttpURLConnection. If you don't want to switch to a different library, you can try to overwrite the method using introspection (yes, that's what Jersey does, see http://java.net/jira/browse/JERSEY-639)

Comment: Thanks! jersey is way to go.

Comment: Link dead. But this should work: https://web.archive.org/web/20150921164541/http://java.net/jira/browse/JERSEY-639

Answer (score 3):

If the server supports it, you can try making a `POST` request with an `X-HTTP-Method-Override: MOVE` header.

Answer (score 2):

I prefer using Apache Http-Components Client. It has a custom networking implementation, thus using non-standard HTTP methods like MOVE or PATCH are possible:

```
CloseableHttpClient httpclient = HttpClients.createDefault();
HttpUriRequest moveRequest = RequestBuilder
            .create("MOVE")
            .setUri("http://example.com")
            .build();        
CloseableHttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(moveRequest);
```

Maven Coordinates:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
    <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
    <version>4.2+</version>
</dependency>
```